# use python to simultaneously submit sql queries and gather result

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I want to execute many sql queries and aggregate result, currently I'm using 'pymssql' for execution and fetching. All queries are submitted in sequential. Is there a way to simultaneously submit multiple queries and fetching result? Something function like 'openmp' in C++?

Comment: Not sure to understand you question but have you looked for python threads ?

Comment: You mean like using a thread or process pool that consumes queries and pushes results back to be aggregated?  Yes.  Look at the `threading` and `multiprocessing` modules in the standard library.  `threading` will probably work well enough for you, but if you start to hit CPU bottlenecks, you can switch to `multiprocessing`.  `threading` effectively uses shared memory by default, basically, and `multiprocessing` provides a mechanism to set up shared memory space as well, though in both cases, you'll probably do just fine using queues, which are simpler.

Comment: Thanks. I'm taking a look.